# Submit button not visible and apply coupon

Tags: magento-1.9, css

on my checkout page of [website](http://www.timports.co.uk),

The apply coupon button and the submit button are not visible in safari. If i hover over the areas you will see what i mean.

I believe this can be changed using css.
Could someone help. Im losing sales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is caused by the following line of you css:

```
button.button span
{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(17deg, #76a843 50%, #7eb347 50%) repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Safari does not natively support the `linear-gradient` property. It uses its own `-webkit-linear-gradient` function.

In order to make your CSS compatible with all browsers, I suggest you follow this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693580/linear-gradient-in-chrome-and-safari-browsers

Comment: Thank you very much, the link will be most helpfull. Now just got to get my head round it.